# I can't get position sticky to work on a header

Tags: css, sticky

I have applied position: sticky to an articles header element but it isn't working.

```
header {
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
 top: 0;
 position: sticky; 
 }
```

The codepen is here http://codepen.io/cssgrid/pen/7a86f94c7d581f913c43a0c7b512ddb0?editors=1100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the floated elements in `.thousand` aren't cleared, `.thousand`'s height is 0 (aside from it's margin). So `header` has nothing to be sticky to.

I made the content of `.thousand` `inline-block` so that you don't have to clear the floats, and that seems to work.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hero_img {
  height: 50vh;
  width:  100%;
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/429997/1920.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.thousand {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 2.5em;
  padding-top: 2.5em;
}

header {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  position: sticky; 
  vertical-align: top;
}

p {
  width: 75%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_img"></div>

<div class="thousand">
  <header>
    <h2>Some Article Title</h2>
    <h3>12th January 2017</h3>
  </header><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel molestiae sapiente labore explicabo earum, eos provident sunt nihil id voluptates, ab eum animi reiciendis accusantium laudantium sit magni nulla corporis nesciunt. Numquam laboriosam quia,
    iure quae ullam, delectus nobis odit id quibusdam aliquam repellat excepturi hic illo amet asperiores magni libero, ducimus nesciunt suscipit quos deleniti! Quo, aspernatur. Numquam laboriosam quia, iure quae ullam, delectus nobis odit id quibusdam
    aliquam repellat excepturi hic illo amet asperiores magni libero, ducimus nesciunt suscipit quos deleniti. Numquam laboriosam quia, iure quae ullam, delectus nobis odit id quibusdam aliquam repellat excepturi hic illo amet asperiores magni libero,
    ducimus nesciunt suscipit quos deleniti! Quo, aspernatur. Natus, animi?</p>
</div>

<div class="thousand">
  <header>
    <h2>Some Article Title</h2>
    <h3>12th January 2017</h3>
  </header><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel molestiae sapiente labore explicabo earum, eos provident sunt nihil id voluptates, ab eum animi reiciendis accusantium laudantium sit magni nulla corporis nesciunt. Numquam laboriosam quia,
    iure quae ullam, delectus nobis odit id quibusdam aliquam repellat excepturi hic illo amet asperiores magni libero, ducimus nesciunt suscipit quos deleniti! Quo, aspernatur. Natus, animi?</p>
</div>

<div class="thousand">
  <header>
    <h2>Some Article Title</h2>
    <h3>12th January 2017</h3>
  </header><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel molestiae sapiente labore explicabo earum, eos provident sunt nihil id voluptates, ab eum animi reiciendis accusantium laudantium sit magni nulla corporis nesciunt. Numquam laboriosam quia,
    iure quae ullam, delectus nobis odit id quibusdam aliquam repellat excepturi hic illo amet asperiores magni libero, ducimus nesciunt suscipit quos deleniti! Quo, aspernatur. Natus, animi?</p>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can give height to `.thousand` by removing the `float` from the `p` element inside of it (the taller element) and just floating `header` (the shorter element)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hero_img {
  height: 50vh;
  width:  100%;
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/429997/1920.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.thousand {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 2.5em;
  padding-top: 2.5em;
}

header {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  top: 0;
  position: sticky; 
}

p {
  width: 75%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_img"></div>

<div class="thousand">
  <header>
    <h2>Some Article Title</h2>
    <h3>12th January 2017</h3>
  </header>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel molestiae sapiente labore explicabo earum, eos provident sunt nihil id voluptates, ab eum animi reiciendis accusantium laudantium sit magni nulla corporis nesciunt. Numquam laboriosam quia,
    iure quae ullam, delectus nobis odit id quibusdam aliquam repellat excepturi hic illo amet asperiores magni libero, ducimus nesciunt suscipit quos deleniti! Quo, aspernatur. Numquam laboriosam quia, iure quae ullam, delectus nobis odit id quibusdam
    aliquam repellat excepturi hic illo amet asperiores magni libero, ducimus nesciunt suscipit quos deleniti. Numquam laboriosam quia, iure quae ullam, delectus nobis odit id quibusdam aliquam repellat excepturi hic illo amet asperiores magni libero,
    ducimus nesciunt suscipit quos deleniti! Quo, aspernatur. Natus, animi?</p>
</div>

<div class="thousand">
  <header>
    <h2>Some Article Title</h2>
    <h3>12th January 2017</h3>
  </header>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel molestiae sapiente labore explicabo earum, eos provident sunt nihil id voluptates, ab eum animi reiciendis accusantium laudantium sit magni nulla corporis nesciunt. Numquam laboriosam quia,
    iure quae ullam, delectus nobis odit id quibusdam aliquam repellat excepturi hic illo amet asperiores magni libero, ducimus nesciunt suscipit quos deleniti! Quo, aspernatur. Natus, animi?</p>
</div>

<div class="thousand">
  <header>
    <h2>Some Article Title</h2>
    <h3>12th January 2017</h3>
  </header>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel molestiae sapiente labore explicabo earum, eos provident sunt nihil id voluptates, ab eum animi reiciendis accusantium laudantium sit magni nulla corporis nesciunt. Numquam laboriosam quia,
    iure quae ullam, delectus nobis odit id quibusdam aliquam repellat excepturi hic illo amet asperiores magni libero, ducimus nesciunt suscipit quos deleniti! Quo, aspernatur. Natus, animi?</p>
</div>
```